Error in dissolving shapefile with ogr2ogr
I am trying to dissolve a shapefile having polygon geometries. I want to dissolve the shapefile which will create a single multi-polygon geometry.
ogr2ogr -dialect sqlite -sql SELECT ST_Union(geometry) AS geometry FROM '93000100_qk21_new' 93000100_qk21_new_1.shp 93000100_qk21_new.shp

The input is 93000100_qk21_new.shp
The output is 93000100_qk21_new_1.shp
I am getting following error,
ERROR 1: In ExecuteSQL(): sqlite3_prepare_v2(SELECT ST_Union(geometry) AS geometry FROM '93000100_qk21_new'):
  wrong number of arguments to function ST_Union()

I changed the command to
ogr2ogr -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ST_Union() AS geometry FROM '93000100_qk21_new' 93000100_qk21_new_1.shp 93000100_qk21_new.shp

still got similar error,
ERROR 1: In ExecuteSQL(): sqlite3_prepare_v2(SELECT ST_Union() AS geometry FROM '93000100_qk21_new'):
  wrong number of arguments to function ST_Union()

I have also tried to run as the following way taking reference from this answer,
ogr2ogr 93000100_qk21_new_1.shp 93000100_qk21_new.shp -dialect sqlite -sql SELECT ST_Union(geometry) FROM 93000100_qk21_new

and got the error as,
ERROR 1: In ExecuteSQL(): sqlite3_prepare_v2(SELECT ST_Union(geometry) FROM 93000100_qk21_new):
  unrecognized token: "93000100_qk21_new"

The ogrinfo 93000100_qk21_new.shp command giving,
INFO: Open of `93000100_qk21_new.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
1: 93000100_qk21_new (Polygon)

What is the issue here? I am not able to figure out what should be the correct command for dissolving shapefile with ogr.
The gdal version is gdal/3.2.0. I am working in Linux based system (CentOS)

Try -sql "SELECT ST_Union(geometry) AS geometry FROM 93000100_qk21_new".

getting ERROR 1: In ExecuteSQL(): sqlite3_prepare_v2(SELECT ST_Union(geometry) AS geometry FROM 93010800_qk21_new):   unrecognized token: "93010800_qk21_new" with the modification

These things needs to be changed to the first command in your question:

At least on windows, you need to put double quotes around the SQL query, otherwise gdal doesn't interprete it as one parameter
The shapefile name, and so the table name in the SQL query, starts with a number. Just like using SQL keywords this is not recommended, but if you need it, you can put double quotes around the table name (reference). Because of the first point, there are already double quotes around the entire SQL query, so the double quotes around the table name need to be escaped, e.g. by putting a backslash before them (\").

Putting it together, this is the result. It works for me on windows and with gdal 3.8:
ogr2ogr -dialect sqlite -sql "SELECT ST_Union(geometry) AS geometry FROM \"93000100_qk21_new\"" 93000100_qk21_new_1.shp 93000100_qk21_new.shp


Maybe more readable when escaped with backslash, FROM \"93000100_qk21_new\"".

Escaping with \ should indeed also work, I suppose the readability depends on personal preference...

Backslash is also the documented escape character "Starting with GDAL 3.9, field names with spaces, commas or double-quote should be surrounded with a starting and ending  double-quote character, and double-quote characters in a field name should be escaped with backslash."

I am working on Linux based system (centos OS). Adding double quotes gave the following error, ERROR 1: In ExecuteSQL(): sqlite3_prepare_v2(SELECT ST_Union(geometry) AS geometry FROM 93000100_qk21_new):   unrecognized token: "93000100_qk21_new"

To be sure: did you also add escaped double quotes around the table name in the SQL query?

@user30184: OK, if that escaping flavour is used in the documentation it is safer to use that.
